# Function holds System Image rather than image

Tags: swiftui

@ViewBuilder

```
func TabButton (image: String)-> some View{

    Button {

        withAnimation{currentTab = image}

    } label: {

        Image(image)

            .resizable()

            .renderingMode(.original)

            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

            .frame(width: 23, height: 22)

            .foregroundColor(currentTab == image ? .primary : .gray)

            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            
    }.buttonStyle(GradientButtonStyle())


}
```

}

I want rather than image from assets as input, system image whom is variable is input here and can change each time and not fixed. thank you

I use it like this,

struct MainView: View {

```
@State var showMenu: Bool = false


// Hiding Native One.

init(){

    UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true

}

@State var currentTab = "Home"



//offset for both drag gesture and showing menu.

@State  var offset: CGFloat = 0

@State  var lastStoredOffset: CGFloat = 0



var body: some View {

    //let sideBarWidth = getRect().width - 90

  // whole navigation view....

    NavigationView{

        HStack(spacing : 0){

           //Side Menu

            //SideMenu(showMenu: $showMenu)

            //Main Tab View

            VStack(spacing: 0){

                TabView(selection: $currentTab){

                     Home(showMenu: $showMenu)

                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                        .navigationBarHidden(true)

                        .tag("Home")
```

}

this is the tabview code up

VStack(spacing: 0)

{
Divider()

```
                HStack(spacing:0){

                   // tab buttons

                TabButton(image: "Home")
```

}

}

}

}

I want system image rather than image here , need help please!

Comment: replace `Image(image)` with `Image(systemName: image)`

Comment: ohh my god ! thank you so much it worked, I didn't thought about it this way 

Comment: I can add the symbols but can't navigate between tabs  it's only reading them as pngs

Comment: I don't see any navigating or Tabs in your code. This might be another question ...

Comment: I did now with some editing thank you, it is not taking it as current tab to select, just taking the system image as an image alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess ... but I think you want something like this?

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    // Hiding Native One.
    init(){
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    @State var currentTab = "house"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //let sideBarWidth = getRect().width - 90
        // whole navigation view....
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack(spacing : 0) {
                //Side Menu
                //SideMenu(showMenu: $showMenu)
                //Main Tab View
                
                TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                    Text("Home Content") //  Home(showMenu: $showMenu)
                        .tag("house")
                    Text("Star Content") //  ...
                        .tag("star")
                    Text("Settings Content") //  ...
                        .tag("gear")
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                
                Divider()
                Spacer(minLength: 10)
                
                HStack {
                    // tab buttons
                    TabButton(image: "house")
                    TabButton(image: "star")
                    TabButton(image: "gear")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func TabButton (image: String)-> some View{
        Button {
            withAnimation{ currentTab = image }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 23, height: 22)
                .foregroundColor( currentTab == image ? .primary : .gray)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
        }
//        .buttonStyle(GradientButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ohh my god worked  there was a problem with the tag acceptance, i really don't know how to thank you, thank you soooo much 